# About sets and algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of subsets os some nonempty set $\Omega$. Suppose that $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$ and that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under the formation of complements and finite disjoint unions. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ need not to be an algebra.

I tried to give some example but every set I think with this properties is an algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Omega:=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathcal F:=\{\varnothing,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

Comment: It was so easy! Thank you